# javascript: detect which variable changed its value

Tags: javascript, xml

Given that I have the following condition to check whether a couple of variables value have changed.

```
<%
if (ctx.recipient.@firstName != ctx.recipient.@firstName_init || ctx.recipient.@lastName != ctx.recipient.@lastName_init || ctx.recipient.@emailPreferredName != ctx.recipient.emailPreferredName_init) 
    {       
        document.controller.setValue('/ctx/vars/piiChanges',1);     
    }
%>
```

How can I detect which of all the 3 conditions value changed?

Here is my XML payload

```
<recipient JOB_TITLE="" 
       blackListEmail="0" 
       cmOneID="0" 
       company="" 
       email="dummy@dummy.com1" 
       emailPreferredName="Dummy1" 
       firstName="Dummy1" 
       id="13246096" 
       initiative="" 
       investorType="" 
       jurisdiction="" 
       lastName="Dummy1" 
       lawfulBasisLabel="None" 
       lawfulBasisName="none" 
       leadScore="0" 
       origin="" 
       status="0" 
       statusLabel="Other" 
       statusName="other" 
       _operation="update" 
       _key="@id" 
       firstName_init="Dummy" 
       lastName_init="Dummy" 
       email_init="dummy@dummy.com" 
       emailPreferredName_init="Dummy" 
       blackListEmail_init="0">
<postalAddress addrDefined="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the data object's properties and get a list of all of the keys that have changed. Something like this:

```js
function getChangedProperties(recipient) {
  const changedProps = [];

  // Loop over each of the property keys of the recipient object
  Object.keys(recipient).forEach(key => {
    // Check non-init values to see if their init counterparts are equal
    if (!key.endsWith("_init") && recipient[`${key}_init`] !== recipient[key]) {
      changedProps.push(key);
    }
  });

  return changedProps;
}
```